# Type error: cant read property of execute

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I dont understand why this is happening because normally the execute error in the console happens because the file name is different from the module.exports name but in this case I literally have no idea what is cause this error (btw I removed choices):

```
module.exports.run = {
    name: 'scavenge',
    aliases: ['scv', 'scav'],
    description: 'go scavenge for coins',
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData){
        const choices = [];
        const choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
        const response = await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate({
            userID: message.author.id,
        }, {
            $inc: {
                Bobux: randomNumber,
            }
        }
        );
        return message.channel.send(`You searched in **${choice}** and found **${randomNumber} Bobux**`);
    }
}

Console:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
```

Comment: How and where do you call the `execute` function?

Comment: scavenge so it is the same

Comment: ? I was asking how and where you call the exported `execute` function. My assumption was what @CharryDT covered in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68245116/12834972).

Comment: Wait do you mean if I have an advanced command handler because I have an event handler formatted:

Handlers
Commands
Models
Events
.env
main.js
package-lock.json
package.json

Answer (score 1):

It should be `module.exports =` and not `module.exports.run =`:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'scavenge',
    aliases: ['scv', 'scav'],
    description: 'go scavenge for coins',
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait sorry that was a mistake it was module.exports and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is copying and pasting code(most likely), this mainly is caused when you don't fully understand the code.

When your are using a commandfile.execute, you cannot use a module.exports.run

Therefore, you must replace:

```js
module.exports.run = {
```

with:

```js
module.exports.execute = {
```

Your index.js file is requiring a .execute while your exporting a .run!

If you need any more help, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

See you're exporting the command files as a javascript `object`, and your error means `execute` property does not exist in the command file object. and it should be `module.exports =` not `module.exports.run =`, so the fix would be

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'scavenge',
    aliases: ['scv', 'scav'],
    description: 'go scavenge for coins',
    execute: async (message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData) => { // defining execute property
        // do your command code here
    }
}
```